# What Type is Storybook Story From Example

Tags: javascript, typescript, storybook

I have used some code from the example on storybook website, specifically:

```
export const Primary = Primary.decorators = [(Story) => <div style={{ margin: '3em' }}><Story/></div>]
```

However, even though this is the typescript example, it does not specify a type for Story and my linter will not pass unless it has a type. What type should I use for Story?

```
Story: any
```

also will not pass.

Reference: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/decorators

Comment: dont' you get a type if you try console.log it?

Comment: It appears to be an array of functions.

Comment: It should be a `ReactNode`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can tell what sort of properties we require from `Story` based on how we use it.  We are expecting that it is something that can be called via JSX with no arguments and return an element.  So you could use `(Story: React.FC)` and that would work.

---

As shown in [this example](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/introduction#using-decorators), you can import the type `Meta` from `@storybook/react` and use that as the type for `Primary`.

```
import { Meta } from "@storybook/react";

const Primary: Meta = {
  title: "MyStory",
  decorators: [
    (Story) => (
      <div style={{ margin: "3em" }}>
        <Story />
      </div>
    )
  ]
};
```

They type for `Story` here is inferred as `() => StoryFnReactReturnType`.

---

You could also import the type for `Story`:

```
import { Story } from "@storybook/react";

export default {
  title: "MyStory",
  decorators: [
    (Story: Story) => (
      <div style={{ margin: "3em" }}>
        <Story />
      </div>
    )
  ]
};
```

Comment: For Component Level decorator usage (your second code snippet), I was unable to get that import to work inside of storybook, but just typing the `Story` as `() => StoryFnReactReturnType` did the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: Since Storybook v8, it's now `import { StoryFn } from '@storybook/react'` instead of `import { Story } from '@storybook/react'` and then `(Story: StoryFn) => (`

Answer (score 13):

With the new story format (CSF 3) the types have been updated :

- the `Story` type is deprecated
- the correct type is now `StoryFn`

The decorator correct typed signature is :

```
import { StoryFn } from '@storybook/react';

export const decorators = [(Story: StoryFn) => <div style={{ margin: '3em' }}><Story/></div>]
```